# Anime involving a space dictator and a little girl with a huge sword which imbued her with certain abilities

Tags: story-identification, anime

When I was a kid, there used to be an anime being aired. It started with the description of a horrific space dictator/bad guy, and there was this little girl with this huge sword, which imbued her with certain abilities when needed.

The villain's name was something like "ALIAS RETININT YALLOW" or something,  It was in Japanese, so I am not sure I remember the correct pronunciation. It had very emotional scenes, with deaths, and heartbreaks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. When exactly did you watch this? If you remember any extra details, please be sure to [edit] them in

Comment: This question is very terse and could be improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example; What was the girl's name? What did she look like? When did you watch the show? How old was the girl? What was the setting? Was this in the future or a fantasy scifi world? Why did she need a sword? Just how big was the sword (bigger than her? Comically large?). Was she fighting the space dictator? Who dies? Whose heart was broken? What abilities did the sword give her?

Comment: Was this a series or a movie?

Comment: A space dictator and a girl with a huge magic sword that gives her powers matches She-Ra, but that's not Japanese, though it might have been translated.  The villain's name isn't what you said either (it's "Hordak"), but that might have been to do with the translation.